# Java change the value of one object

Tags: java

```
public class Test {
    public Integer num = 1;

    public void change(Integer n) {
        n = null;
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(num);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.change(test.num);
        test.print();
    }
}
```

Why I can not change the value of the object "num" in above code? How to revise it to achieve the operation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Answer (score 3):

```
public void change(Integer n) {
    n = null;
}
```

`n` is a *local* variable.

Change it to `num = null`

If you want to make the value of `num` to null (as you said in the comments), there is no need to pass anything as a parameter. This will do.

```
public void makeNull() { //or call it setNull
    num = null;
}
```

Also, don't make `num` public. Make it private. It is a good practice (and a must follow one IMO unless you have a strong reason)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what is provided in other answers, Java is pass-by-value. When you call a function with primitive variables as arguments, called function will use its own local copy of the variable you used as argument. It will only extract the value of that variable. Changes to the parameter variable in the called function will not effect the original variable.